# ++ in vim commands

Tags: vim, vi

What does `++` mean in vim?

For example, `:e ++ff=dos`. I understand `e` and `ff=dos`, just not sure how `++` fits in there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`:h ++opt` for detail

```
The [++opt] argument can be used to force the value of 'fileformat',
'fileencoding' or 'binary' to a value for one command, and to specify the
behavior for bad characters.  The form is: >
    ++{optname}
Or: >
    ++{optname}={value}

Where {optname} is one of:      *++ff* *++enc* *++bin* *++nobin* *++edit*
    ff     or  fileformat   overrides 'fileformat'
    enc    or  encoding     overrides 'fileencoding'
    bin    or  binary       sets 'binary'
    nobin  or  nobinary     resets 'binary'
    bad             specifies behavior for bad characters
    edit            for |:read| only: keep option values as if editing
                a file
```

the cmd in your question:

```
:e ++ff=dos
```

means editing the same file again with fileformat set to "dos"

Answer (score 4):

`++` is used to FORCE values for commands like `ff`,`enc` and others.

Use `:h ++` to look this up yourself in the vim help!

Comment: great thanks! for some reason i assumed `:h` wouldnt accept non-word characters and didnt think to try.

Comment: There is also `:helpgrep`... if this also does not work, just plain `grep -i -r --color=auto 'searchterm'` the folder with vim's manual... :D

Comment: tau, do you have fuzzyfinder installed? it could search through vim help.

Comment: If you want a Vim with plugins, use the `Vundle` plugin manager. Don't bother with the others, they are just worse.